# C++ combine images croped from the one photo

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have 400x400 photo. I took the pieces as 4 separate photos of 100 * 400 and recorded them as 1, 2, 3, 4.jpg.

I have to combine 4 images croped from the one photo and get the original photo of 400 * 400. How can I do it ?

I don't want to use a ready(set) function. I need to do with for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use available functions, you can create a 400x400 mask and assign the pixel values of each piece to the mask.

Here is the code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main() {

    // 4 Pieces
    Mat piece_1 = imread("/ur/image/directory/1.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat piece_2 = imread("/ur/image/directory/2.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat piece_3 = imread("/ur/image/directory/3.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat piece_4 = imread("/ur/image/directory/4.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    // Mask
    Mat source_image = Mat::zeros(Size(400,400),CV_8UC1);

    for(int i=0;i<source_image.rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<source_image.cols;j++)
        {
            if(i<=99)
                source_image.at<uchar>(i,j)=piece_1.at<uchar>(i,j);
            if(i>99 && i<=199)
                source_image.at<uchar>(i,j)=piece_2.at<uchar>(i-100,j);
            if(i>199 && i<=299)
                source_image.at<uchar>(i,j)=piece_3.at<uchar>(i-200,j);
            if(i>299 && i<=399)
                source_image.at<uchar>(i,j)=piece_4.at<uchar>(i-300,j);
        }
    }

    imshow("Result",source_image);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not going to be easy. Just reading a JPG without using a library could take weeks or months for a professional.

You should use a library. I would recommend **CImg** from [here](https://cimg.eu/) as a good starting point.

Failing that, I would suggest using **ImageMagick** to convert your JPGs to [NetPBM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm) PPM format then you can read them **much** more easily.

```
magick 1.jpg -depth 8 1.ppm
```

When you have written the code to combine them, you can convert the combined PPM file back into a JPG with:

```
magick combined.ppm combined.jpg
```